# No instance for (Show a) arising from a use of `X'

Tags: haskell, gadt

With this code

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
data X a where
     X :: (Show a, Num a) => a -> X a

instance Show (X a) where
         show (X x) = "X " ++ show x

instance Num (X a) where
         fromInteger x = X $ fromInteger x
```

I get this error:

```
No instance for (Show a) arising from a use of `X'
Possible fix:
  add (Show a) to the context of the instance declaration
In the expression: X
In the expression: X $ fromInteger x
In an equation for `fromInteger': fromInteger x = X $ fromInteger x
```

Can anyone explain why I get this error message?

Comment: The error message shows that the problem is in `X $ fromInteger x`, and that it can't be guaranteed that `Show a` exists (for `fromInteger x`). This `Show a` is required by the definition of constructor `X`. To fix this, you must *somehow* add the guarantee `Show a` (and `Num a`) to your `Num (X a)` instance. Maybe this is enough for you to answer your own question.

Comment: So, there is no way to overcome this issue, without adding explicitely (Show a, Num a) => to all functions and instances defined for X a ?

Comment: Nope. That's why you rarely see this pattern.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083508/type-classes-in-haskell-data-types

Comment: use `instance Show a => Show (X a) where ...` and `instance Num a => Num (X a) where ...`

Comment: @viorior: no. The `Show a` is superfluous in the `Show` instance, while `Num a` is insufficient in the `Num` instance.

Comment: The instance heads should read `instance Show (X a)` and `instance (Show a, Num a) => Num (X a)`. Only in the `Num` instance you construct a value using `X`, so it needs the guarantee. In `Show`, you already got the `Show a` you need in the constructor.

Comment: Also see https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/NoDatatypeContexts

Comment: There is no good reason to place type class constraints inside of a constructor for a type which is a parameter to the datatype. It would be better to refactor your code to remove the constraint inside the constructor and just place it where it is required (ie - instance declarations and functions).

Answer (score 4):

The correct solution is to add the constraints to the instance head, like so:

```
instance (Show a, Num a) => Num (X a) where
         fromInteger x = X $ fromInteger x
```

Clearly you can't treat a `X String` as a `Num` for example.

Answer (score -1):

Because GHC stopped having `Show` as a superclass of `Num`.  If `Show` were still a superclass of `Num` (the way it is in the Haskell 2010 Report), the use of fromInteger would allow the compiler to deduce (Show a).

Of course, the Haskell 2010 Report doesn't have GADTs.

Comment: Downvoted, because this answer appears to miss the target: the problem here has to do with the GADT constructor definition demanding `Num` and `Show` instances but the constructor use not providing them. Even if `Show` were a superclass of `Num` this would still be a problem.

Comment: If `Show` was a superclass of `Num`, the constructor use *would* be providing both.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. The type signature near the constructor use provides _neither_ `Show` nor `Num` (though  both are required), so the subclassing situation is irrelevant.

Comment: The fromInteger call forces a `Num` constraint.  If `Show` is a superclass of `Num` it also, indirectly, forces a `Show` constraint.

Comment: The instance claims it can work for any `a`. But it can't. It can only work for an `a` which is an instance of `Num` (and hence can be the result type of a call to `fromInteger`). [Here is an ideone showing that you are wrong and that the old class hierarchy does not help.](http://ideone.com/ptzmiS)